# Convert this Redshift function to azure SQL DW

Tags: amazon-redshift, azure-synapse

I want to know how to convert this query from Redshift to Azure SQL DW ?

```
to_char(date_add('ms', vw.datetb, vw.date col), 'MM/DD/YY HH:MI:SS
AM')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Azure SQL Data Warehouse does not have the `FORMAT` function so I think you would have to piece together a couple of calls to `CONVERT` using its format switches, sommething like this:

```
SELECT *,
    CONVERT( CHAR(8), DATEADD( millisecond, vw.datetb, vw.dateCol ), 1 )
    + ' ' + RIGHT( CONVERT( CHAR(20), DATEADD( millisecond, vw.datetb, vw.dateCol ), 22 ), 11 ) 
FROM yourTable vw
```

My results:

[image: My results]